# Client want ASP.NET application in URDU

Tags: asp.net, globalization, urdu

my client want asp.net application in urud to keep track of its clients billing information. any suggestion how to do this all the labels text, textboxes every thing should be in urdu ?

Comment: What's preventing this from happening?  .NET doesn't care what characters are used for any given string, so as long as the application supports the necessary character sets then what's the problem?

Comment: please do some basic research before posting questions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9(v=vs.140).aspx